# Jenkins controller can't connect to the agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh

I'm trying out Jenkins and its been fun so far. I've been able to build a pipeline, pair it to my Github etc. Now I am trying to create an agent and connect with my controller but I'm getting connection refused.

My Jenkins controller is hosted locally on a docker container and I have a container running for the agent as well. I used this doc for reference: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/

I suspect maybe a SSH service issue or maybe my ssh keys are messed up. Although the sshd is running on the agent:

```
43b3773b:/home/jenkins/.ssh# ps -ef
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D -e [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
```

And I have the jenkins controller pub key in authorized_keys:

```
a81443b3773b:/home/jenkins# cat .ssh/authorized_keys 
ssh-rsa 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 jenkins@4cfbfa97f71d
```

This is the command I used to start the agent:

```
docker run -d --rm --name=agent1 -p 4444:22 -e "JENKINS_AGENT_SSH_PUBKEY=ssh-rsa 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 jenkins@4cfbfa97f71d" jenkins/ssh-agent:alpine-jdk17
```

The pubkey is of my Jenkins controller.

On my localhost port 4444 is open.

This is the error I get in Jenkins agent log:

```
SSHLauncher{host='0.0.0.0', port=4444, credentialsId='jenkins2', jvmOptions='', javaPath='', prefixStartSlaveCmd='', suffixStartSlaveCmd='', launchTimeoutSeconds=60, maxNumRetries=10, retryWaitTime=2, sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy=hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.ManuallyTrustedKeyVerificationStrategy, tcpNoDelay=true, trackCredentials=true}
[12/04/23 18:42:20] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 0.0.0.0:4444.
Connection refused
SSH Connection failed with IOException: "Connection refused", retrying in 2 seconds. There are 10 more retries left.
Connection refused
```

Here are my containers btw:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                                      NAMES
a81443b3773b   jenkins/ssh-agent:alpine-jdk17   "setup-sshd"             48 minutes ago   Up 41 minutes   0.0.0.0:4444->22/tcp, :::4444->22/tcp                                                      agent1
4cfbfa97f71d   jenkins/jenkins:lts              "/usr/bin/tini -- /u…"   5 days ago       Up 55 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp, :::50000->50000/tcp   brave_pascal
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: did you create public key using this comand : ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/jenkins_agent_key

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan yup, i used that on my master and then used the pub key to create the agent container as shown and used the private key in my jenkins credentials config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get it working.
Had to use the IP of the agent container and port 22 instead of 4444.